# Tooltip html formatted in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, tooltip

Is there a tooltip that reads html format text in angular 2?

I have not found anything about this in this forum

Comment: Your question is too broad and opinion based. Consider making your own tooltip, or specify an issue you have with an existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use PrimeNg as a component library for angular development.
It provides a lot of useful components and it also has a tooltip component.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tooltip

Make sure you put the [escape] property to false to support HTML tags in the content of the tooltip.